# Keeping Tree layout when using connections between branches in Dot/Graphviz

Tags: tree, graphviz, dot

I am implementing a Frequent Pattern Tree at the moment. For visualization I am using dot/graphviz (especially wintersleep-graphviz 0.1, but this should not concern us now), which is working fine so far.

When visualizing node links, which are connections between the branches, the tree layout breaks. How can I prevent this?

Example:
[Ordinary Tree](http://i60.tinypic.com/301dm55.png)
Code:

```
#!/bin/env dot
digraph FrequentPatternTree30 {
# attributeListListList:

# attributeList:


# child graphs:
# nodes:
30 [label="root"]
31 [label="f:4"]
32 [label="c:2"]
34 [label="c:1"]
33 [label="b:2"]
35 [label="b:1"]

# edges:
30 -> 31
 ;
31 -> 32
 ;
30 -> 34
 ;
32 -> 33
 ;
34 -> 35
 ;
}
```

[Tree with Node Links](http://de.tinypic.com/r/11mgncg/8)
Code:

```
#!/bin/env dot
digraph FrequentPatternTree30 {
# attributeListListList:

# attributeList:


# child graphs:
# nodes:
30 [label="root"]
31 [label="f:4"]
32 [label="c:2"]
34 [label="c:1"]
33 [label="b:2"]
35 [label="b:1"]

# edges:
30 -> 31
 ;
31 -> 32
 ;
30 -> 34
 ;
32 -> 34
 [style="dotted"];
32 -> 33
 ;
34 -> 35
 ;
33 -> 35
 [style="dotted"];
}
```

I am sorry, if the example images are not shown properly, but my reputation is still too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding those edges with the attribute `constraint=false` in order to not have them influence the ranking of the nodes.

Comment: Works for me, thank you! +1 (Vote Up requires 15 reputation:( )